# Convert textual response to command to binary 0 or 1

Tags: bash, shell

So I can query FreePBX from the command line "are the office phones on day or night mode" using this command:
`rasterisk -x "database get DAYNIGHT C0"`
I then get as a response:
`Value: NIGHT` or `Value: DAY`.

I then want to be able to call this as a script and for that script to return 0 if the response is Value: DAY and 1 if the response was Value: NIGHT.

Any ideas how I would go about doing this?!

Thank you!

This is to integrate with Home Assistant so Home Assistant knows the state of my office PABX

```
switch:
  - platform: command_line
    switches:
      kitchen_light:
        command_on: switch_command on kitchen
        command_off: switch_command off kitchen
        command_state: Returning a result code 0 will indicate that the switch is on.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the value first and then conditionally `echo` what you need.

```
resp="Value: DAY"  # load this variable with the response string
val="${resp#*: }"  # remove the prefix
if [[ "$val" == DAY ]]; then
    echo 0
elif [[ "$val" == NIGHT ]]; then 
    echo 1
else
    echo Invalid  # to handle unexpected responses
fi
```

You can write the conditional in single line,

```
[[ "$val" == DAY ]] && echo 0 || { [[ "$val" == NIGHT ]] && echo 1 || echo Invalid; }
```

Refer to [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for more information regarding `Bash` string manipulation.

Comment: You shouldn't generally chain `&&` and `||` to replace `if...elif...else...fi` because the results of statements can affect the evaluation of subsequent conditionals. This means that the chain you show is not equivalent to the `if` statement shown. In the simple case here it's not expected that `echo` will have a non-zero exit code, but in slightly more complex uses it is very much possible. It's perfectly fine, however, to chain any number of only `&&` clauses or to use a single `||` between two statements (multiple `II` would be unusual). By the way, the ABS is a poor resource because ...